# Using cout with two expressions in a class

Tags: c++, class, cout

I am making a class called Time in C++ and the class has 3 integers as private member variables. I am pretty new at using classes in C++ and am trying to figure out how to solve this particular problem. The problem is that when I try to do this:

```
cout << "Almost midnight: " << Time(0,0,0) - Time(0,0,1) << endl;
```

I get a compiler error and I think it is because the constructor that takes 3 parameters needs to be coded differently because the private variables in the class take the value from the first constructor and then tries to subtract from the value from the second constructor so the first values get lost (I believe). So how does the constructor need to be in order to keep the old values so I can do the subtraction without storing it in a named variable.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
    private:
     int hours;
     int minutes;
     int seconds;
     void normalize();
    public:
     Time() {hours = minutes = seconds = 0; normalize();};
     Time(int x, int y, int z);
     friend Time operator + (const Time& t1, const Time& t2);
     friend Time operator - (const Time& t1, const Time& t2);
     friend bool operator < (const Time& t1, const Time& t2);
     friend istream& operator >>(istream& ins, Time& t1);
     friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Time& t1);
};

Time::Time(int x, int y, int z)
{
    hours = x;
    minutes = y;
    seconds = z;

    normalize();
}

void Time::normalize()
{
    int s = seconds;
    int m = minutes;
    int h = hours;

    while(s < 0)
    {
        s += 60;
        m--;
    }

    while(m < 0)
    {
        m += 60;
        h--;
    }

    while(h < 0)
    {
        h = h + 24;
    }

    seconds = s % 60;
    minutes = (m + s/60) % 60;
    hours = (h + m/60 + s/3600) % 24;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& ins, Time& t1)
{
    ins >> t1.hours;
    ins >> t1.minutes;
    ins >> t1.seconds;

    t1.normalize();

    return ins;
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Time& t1)
{
    if(t1.hours < 10)
        out << '0' << t1.hours << ":";
    else
        out << t1.hours << ":";
    if(t1.minutes < 10)
        out << '0' << t1.minutes << ":";
    else
        out << t1.minutes << ":";
    if(t1.seconds < 10)
        out << '0' << t1.seconds;
    else
        out << t1.seconds;

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Time t1, t2, t3, t4;
    cin >> t1;
    cin >> t2;
    cin >> t3;

    cout << "Time1: " << t1 << endl;
    cout << "Time2: " << t2 << endl;
    cout << "Time3: " << t3 << endl;

    t4 = t1 + t2;
    cout << "Time4: " << t4 << endl;

    t1 = t3 - t4;
    cout << "Time1: " << t1 << endl;

    if (t1 < t3)
        cout << "Time1 < Time3" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Time3 >= Time1" << endl;

    Time t5 = t2 + Time(0,0,1);
    if (t5 < t2)
        cout << "Time5 < Time2" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Time5 >= Time2" << endl;

    cout << "Almost midnight: " << Time(0,0,0) - Time(0,0,1) << endl;

    return 0;
}

Time operator + (const Time& t1, const Time& t2)
{
    Time temp;
    temp.hours = t1.hours + t2.hours;
    temp.minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes;
    temp.seconds = t1.seconds + t2.seconds;

    return temp;
}

Time operator - (const Time& t1, const Time& t2)
{
    Time temp;

    temp.hours = t1.hours - t2.hours;
    temp.minutes = t1.minutes - t2.minutes;
    temp.seconds = t1.seconds - t2.seconds;

    temp.normalize();

    return temp;
}

bool operator < (const Time& t1, const Time& t2)
{
    if(t1.hours < t2.hours && t1.minutes < t2.minutes && t1.seconds < t2.seconds)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not even telling us what the compiler error is...

Comment: |122|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"Almost midnight: ")) << operator-((*(const Time*)(& Time(0, 0, 0))), (*(const Time*)(& Time(0, 0, 1))))'|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time(0,0,0) - Time(0,0,1)` is gives a temporary object (rvalue)

Use `const Time&` for overloaded `<<` operator

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Time& t1);
//                                        ~~~~ Use const
```

Comment: I see, what does it do exactly? It seems to work :)